# Make a radio-streaming PC pretend to be a mass-storage USB device

Tags: windows-vista, usb, audio, music, streaming

- I'm listening to a net radio on my PC
- I want the sound to go through my boombox cause it has nice speakers/amp
- The boombox has no "incoming" audio jack that just plays what comes over the wire
- However the boombox has a USB jack where you can put a thumbdrive with music.
- **The question**: How do I make the PC pretend to be a `mass-storage device`, and dynamically send all received audiodata to the boombox over a symmetric male USB cable?

Failing that, at least tell me how to do it for *local* files (rather than streams).

OS: Vista

Comment: Probably impossible to do because a PC is a USB host as well as the Boom box and two hosts can't communicate with one another. Additionally, you'd need some kind of USB "splitter" if you thought about getting the PC to save to a thumb drive and simultaneously have the speakers read from it - I doubt these exist and probably wouldn't work This brings a final problem: will you be "chopping" the stream to make individual readable files? The boom box probably doesn't have any ability to notice new files on-the-fly and will need to re-initialise the storage for new songs...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to do the means you ask, but I think I have a solution for the same end result: an FM Transmitter.

I use this at home to get my podcasts to my waterproof radio in the shower.

I started with a cheap one intended for a small MP3 player, and later hacked an old USB cable to it for power. Its working good, just not quite the range I want. You can find more powerful ones floating around Amazon or other services. [Here's one I was looking at buying](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000E6I1N).

I originally set it up because I was tired of morning radio, and I've found more uses for it as I've gone. I can expand if you'd like.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. But for this money I'd rather get a good set of PC speakers.

Comment: @monov: Keep in mind that the one I'm currently using was had for $15.00 USD (-ish, might have been a little less). The only reason I'm looking for something a little more beefy is because some days I don't get the strongest signal across the house.

Answer (score 1):

you can't.

and streaming requires a networking capable device at the receiving end.

Comment: The receiving end is my PC. My PC is networking-capable.

Comment: @monov - no, the receiving end would be your boombox, as in receiving the audio stream from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

If your boombox had a line-in socket or something similar, then this would be exactly the problem that Logitech's Squeezebox products (such as the [Squeezebox Duet](http://www.logitechsqueezebox.com/products/squeezebox-duet.html)) are meant to solve.

As it apparently doesn't then I'm not sure there's much that can help you.

Is there any reason why you can't just load all your music on a small USB thumbdrive, and plug that in the player's USB socket to use as it was meant to be? You can quite easily and cheaply pick up small 16GB thumbdrives now, you really need to be going some to be able to fill that with music.

Comment: Mainly because you can't put a net-radio on a thumbdrive. Also I'm just curious if it's possible.